# Trying to center one column with content to the left in CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a design to implement that is supposed to have a centered column of shortcuts and then a text to the left of each.
It should look like this:
[image: Sketch]

The column of the shortcuts should be centered below the title.

I can't get this to work with a responsive design.
The markup I have is ATM this:

```
<div class="ax-learn__shortcuts">
 <h2>Learn shortcuts</h2>
 <div class="ax-learn__shortcuts-row">
   <div>Go to home:</div>
   <div><kbd>g</kbd>then<kbd>h</kbd></div>
 </div>
 <div class="ax-learn__shortcuts-row">
   <div>Go to search:</div>
   <div><kbd>g</kbd>then<kbd>s</kbd></div>
 </div>
 <div class="ax-learn__shortcuts-row">
   <div>Go to learn:</div>
   <div><kbd>g</kbd>then<kbd>l</kbd></div>
 </div>
```

And the current CSS, which doesn't center it perfectly at all, is this:

```
.ax-learn__shortcuts {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ax-learn__shortcuts h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.ax-learn__shortcuts-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And here's an example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/stinaq/pen/RgroXN)

Comment: What is the responsive design you want to achieve with this?

Comment: 1 vote-up for nice pic explanation

Comment: @Senthe Just that the width of the parent is unknown, so I can't set any fixed pixel sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding a pseudo as a *ghost* element, that matches the labels on the left, you can set that and the left labels to `flex: 1`, and they will take all available space and leave the `kbd` in the middle.

Then `text-align: right` for labels and `margin: 0 10px` for `kbd`, and it will look nice too :)

I added these rules, to achieve that.

```
.ax-learn__shortcuts-row::after {
  content: '';
}
.ax-learn__shortcuts-row::after,
.ax-learn__shortcuts-row div:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1;
}
.ax-learn__shortcuts-row div:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}
.ax-learn__shortcuts-row div:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRGNZo)

Stack snippet

```css
.ax-learn__shortcuts-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.ax-learn__shortcuts-row::after {
  content: '';
}

.ax-learn__shortcuts-row::after,
.ax-learn__shortcuts-row div:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1;
}

.ax-learn__shortcuts-row div:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}

.ax-learn__shortcuts-row div:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.ax-learn__shortcuts {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.ax-learn__shortcuts kbd {
  padding: 7px 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ax-learn__shortcuts kbd:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.ax-learn__shortcuts kbd:last-of-type {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.ax-learn__shortcuts h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ax-learn__shortcuts">
  <h2>Learn shortcuts</h2>
  <div class="ax-learn__shortcuts-row">
    <div>Go to home:</div>
    <div><kbd>g</kbd>then<kbd>h</kbd></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ax-learn__shortcuts-row">
    <div>Go to search:</div>
    <div><kbd>g</kbd>then<kbd>s</kbd></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ax-learn__shortcuts-row">
    <div>Go to learn:</div>
    <div><kbd>g</kbd>then<kbd>l</kbd></div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a table without borders for aligning and give it a relative width, just so it can scale to screen size.